Why does MacOS permission popup dismissed automatically?
I'm creating a plugin for Final Cut Pro and when I add the observable for the timeline it shows the popup asking for Automation permissions.
The problem is that the popup stays visible only for 1 second and dismisses itself automatically, adding the observable but it doesn't have the permissions to get the data.
Here's the code in question:
let host = ProExtensionHostSingleton() as! FCPXHost
    if host.timeline != nil {
      host.timeline!.add(timelineObserver)
    }

Here's what is inside of timelineObserver:
class TimelineObserver: NSObject, FCPXTimelineObserver {
    func activeSequenceChanged() {
        let host = ProExtensionHostSingleton() as! FCPXHost
        let hasTimeline: Bool = host.timeline?.activeSequence != nil
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("timelineChanged"), object: nil, userInfo: ["hasTimeline": hasTimeline])
      print("AAA", hasTimeline)
    }
    
    func playheadTimeChanged() {}
    
    func sequenceTimeRangeChanged() {}
}

I know that the problem resides in the line host.timeline!.add(timelineObserver) because removing it, stops the permission popup.
I want the popup to stay visible until the user clicks on it.
